# Excel Power Query import of MySQL data

Tags: mysql, excel, powerquery

I'm hoping there is a simple answer to this as I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

I am using Excel power query to import some data from a mysql table into an excel file. I only want the data and not all the formatting that seems to be applied whenever I import.

I've gone through all the options and cant seem to find a setting where this can be managed.

Comment: What formatting do you mean? Can you be more clear (maybe with some examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query sets an Excel Table Style (green and white).  Select any cell in the table and you can change the Table Style e.g. Table Tools / Design ribbon, Table Styles / Clear.